# Can't run heroku local after following the Heroku Node.js tutorial

Tags: node.js, heroku

I followed the [Getting Started on Heroku with Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs) tutorial.

I used to be able to run `heroku local`. However, after completing some assignments and changing some code, I now get the following error:

```
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 | node:events:505
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |        ^
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |  Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
```

I even created a new app following the exact same steps from the tutorial but it still shows this error.

Here is the full error:

```
filipomarcellino@Filipos-MacBook-Air cmpt276-filipo % heroku local           
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
12:01:47 p.m. web.1 |  > node-js-getting-started@0.3.0 start
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |  > node index.js
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |  node:events:505
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |        ^
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |  Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |      at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1372:16)
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |      at listenInCluster (node:net:1420:12)
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |      at Server.listen (node:net:1508:7)
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |      at Function.listen (/Users/filipomarcellino/cmpt276-filipo/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24)
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/filipomarcellino/cmpt276-filipo/index.js:10:4)
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |      at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |  Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |      at emitErrorNT (node:net:1399:8)
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |    code: 'EADDRINUSE',
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |    errno: -48,
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |    syscall: 'listen',
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |    address: '::',
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |    port: 5000
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 |  }
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
12:01:48 p.m. web.1 Exited with exit code null
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by the error message in your question, `heroku local` is attempting to run your app on port `5000` but that port is already taken by another process.

You can run your app on a different port using the `-p` flag, as follows:

```shell
heroku local -p 3000
```

For other options available to the `heroku local` command, see the [Running Apps Locally > Start your app locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#run-your-app-locally-using-the-heroku-local-command-line-tool-start-your-app-locally) section of [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/).